# Perl | Однострочная обработка массива. Теория и синтаксис

Tags: perl, active-perl

Добрый день,

Вопрос теоретический. Прекрасно знаю, что можно сделать иначе (классический while)

Хочу открыть текстовый файл со списком доменов, одна строка - один домен.
И заполнить ими массив.

```
my $filename = 'domains.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
     or die "Error open file '$filename' $!";
```

Хочу заполнение сделать в одну строку, без while. Логически понимаю, что можно соединить по примеру с grep

```
my @domains =   grep /\.com/x , <$fh>; # в массив попадут лишь записи удовлетворящие фильтру
```

Вместо grep делаю chomp и получаю облом

```
my @domains =   chomp , <$fh>;
```

Ругается на неопределенную $_ , но попытки указать явно тоже ни к чему не приводят

```
my @domains =   chomp $_ , $_ = <$fh>;
```

Нельзя чтоли? ))

p.s. Во! по наводке @KoVadim сделал так

```
my $filename = 'domains.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
     or die "Error open file '$filename' $!";
chomp (my @domains =  <$fh>);
```

Comment: Почему работает с grep и не работает с chomp станет очевидным, если расставить скобки: `grep(/\.com/x, <$fh>)` vs `chomp($_, $_=<$fh>)`. Вы же хотите что-то вроде `chomp for <$fh>`.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так `chomp , <$fh>;` точно нельзя писать. Во первых, потому, что аргумент явно пропущен. А во вторых, chomp модифицирует свой аргумент, а с хедлером он это сделать не может (теоренически это возможно - перезаписать файл, но хендл может указывать не только на файл).

Но можно написать так:

```
my @domains =  <$fh>; chomp @domains;
```

Comment: Во! 
chomp (my @domains =  <$fh>);

Answer (score 2):

p.s. Во! по наводке @KoVadim сделал так

```
my $filename = 'domains.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
     or die "Error open file '$filename' $!";
chomp (my @domains =  <$fh>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы, кстати, поосторожнее с chomp. Как гласит документация, chomp removes any trailing string that corresponds to the current value of $/. Так вот если будет файл с другими разделителями строк, могут возникнуть проблемы.